# How to hide a successful assertion log on Cypress Desktop, but show a failed one?

Tags: logging, cypress

I have been wondering how to hide a successful assertion log on Cypress Desktop (npx cypress open), but show a failed one?
[image: cypress UI]

I have been searching in stackoverflow (for similar question), documentation and the closes one I find is only `CYPRESS_NO_COMMAND_LOG=1`. but, that is not the result what I am expecting. because when I do that, it just minimizing the runner and it's actually not running my test cases. hence, no result of all assertion.

Comment: This is not possible currently, but there is an open issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7693#issuecomment-643899337 (there are also some suggestions and workarounds in that issue thread)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.should()` assertion uses the [Cypress.log()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cypress-log) method to output messages

> This is the internal API for **controlling what gets printed** to the Command Log.
>
> Useful when writing your own custom commands.

So you can use it to filter out the passing assertions.

---

In the following example, the `<h1>` text content is successfully asserted, but the log is suppressed.

```js
const originalLog = Cypress.log
Cypress.log = (log) => {
  if (log.name === 'assert' && log.passed === true) return
  originalLog(log)
}

cy.visit('https://example.com')
cy.get('h1')
  .should('have.text', 'Example Domain')
```

[image]

If I add a second ***failing*** assertion, the details are logged

```js
cy.get('h1')
  .should('have.text', 'Example Domain')
  .and('have.text', 'Cypress')
```

[image]